# How to implement this Rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am very new to URL rewrites I can do the really really basic stuff but I am stuck on this, my client has requested that I implement the following for there site:

https://domain.com/[PATH]?[PARAMS] ..should be interpreted as such: domain.com/index.php?i=[PATH]&[PARAMS] [PATH] will be a string containing any kind of character except ?, =, & or #. [PARAMS] will be a string of standard URL-encoded query parameters Examples: domain.com/site/home -> domain.comt/index.php?i=site/home domain.com/user/view?id=123 -> /domain.com/index.php?i=user/view&id=123

any help would be appreciated

Joe

Answer (score 0):

This would work I guess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Check if file or folder exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/?$ index.php?i=$1 [QSA, L]
```